# Django Admin Page Shuts down immediately

Tags: python, django

whenever i start the server at http://127.0.0.1:8000 the page loads perfectly but when i add the admin page, the server shuts instantly without any error alert on the terminal.

```
(envr4) C:\Users\xxxx\djangoprojects\personal>python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'xxxxxxxx'):
Email address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.

(envr4) C:\Users\xxxxx\djangoprojects\personal>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 24, 2020 - 11:00:32
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'my_portfolio.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2037
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:42] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2088
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:54] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:55] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:56] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:57] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:57] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1233
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:57] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:57] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:57] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:58] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[24/Jan/2020 11:00:58] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[24/Jan/2020 11:01:14] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

(envr4) C:\Users\xxxxx\djangoprojects\personal>
```

Comment: It's to less info to tell something. From the log it's only visible that you are seeing the logic page and after providing the credentials all stops. Did you run migrations?

Comment: this is an [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31067) with django 3.0, try to upgrade your python version to 3.7.x.